# Why doesn't my sql syntax work for creating a view?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell my why SQL keeps giving back errors when I try to create a view?

```
create view VAR_PEAKING as 
     select MEASURE_1 as PKN_1, MEASURE_2 as PKN_2, MEASURE_3 as PKN_3
     from LIVE_MEAS
      WHERE VARIABLE = 'PKN',
      select MEASURE_1 as PKS_1, MEASURE_2 as PKS_2, MEASURE_3 as PKS_3
     from LIVE_MEAS
      WHERE VARIABLE = 'PKS'
```

Comment: You should share more info with us in order to get some help. What is your table's structure, how the above SELECT statements related to eachother. It is a good idea to share sample data and desired output too and create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) demo which contains the structure and sample data. Please read the [ask] article in [help].

Comment: From what I see, you should consider re-design your table properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both `SELECT` statements return rows, how's this? (`UNION`, not a comma)

```
create view VAR_PEAKING as 
select 
    MEASURE_1 as PKN_1,
    MEASURE_2 as PKN_2,
    MEASURE_3 as PKN_3,
    NULL AS pks_1,
    NULL AS pks_2,
    NULL AS pks_3
from LIVE_MEAS
WHERE VARIABLE = 'PKN'
UNION
select
    NULL AS pkn_1,
    NULL AS pkn_2,
    NULL AS pkn_3,
    MEASURE_1 as PKS_1,
    MEASURE_2 as PKS_2,
    MEASURE_3 as PKS_3
from LIVE_MEAS
WHERE VARIABLE = 'PKS'
```

Any chance of you posting sample data, data structures, and the desired results?

This may be what you're looking for:

```
create view VAR_PEAKING as 
SELECT
    a.MEASURE_1 as PKN_1,
    a.MEASURE_2 as PKN_2,
    a.MEASURE_3 as PKN_3, 
    b.MEASURE_1 as PKS_1, 
    b.MEASURE_2 as PKS_2, 
    b.MEASURE_3 as PKS_3
from LIVE_MEAS a JOIN LIVE_MEAS b ON a.[col]=b.[col]
WHERE a.VARIABLE = 'PKN' AND b.VARIABLE = 'PKS'
```

Comment: The table needs to have 6 columns, PKN_1, PKN_2, PKN_3, PKS_1, PKS_2, PKS_3